# Negative instances are far more than positive instances, how to solve?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Im my project, there are many negative instance, and negative instances are far more than positive instances, I have trained a model with deep learning method, the precision on my train set and validate set are higher than test set. 
How can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You can assign a higher `loss_weight` to positive class than to the negative class.

Comment: Adding variants with noise to positive samples might help.

Comment: Do you mean your instance in training sets? then you can augment your data by different methods.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Yes, I did it like you said, but the validation loss cannot decrease, the first loss is minimal. could you tell me how to solve overfitting.

Comment: Try data augmentation as mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: Maybe a few libraries available in python will be of help for data imbalance. Like https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn